# incorrect assignment inside of loop fscanf

Tags: arrays, c, string, file, pointers

I have an array of pointers that i created using calloc that i'm using it to store strings inside it, and i'm collecting data from a file using fscanf.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
    FILE *fp;
    int length,i;
    fp = fopen("file.txt", "r");
     if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("Error opening file\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    char str[5];
    char  **rot = calloc(length,5);
    fscanf(fp,"%d",&length);
    for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                if (fscanf(fp, "%s",str) == 1)
                {
                    rot[i] = str;
                    printf("%s\n",rot[i]);
                }
                else
                {
                    break;
                }
        }

    printf("element: %s\n",rot[1]);
    printf("element: %s\n",rot[0]);
    printf("element: %s\n",rot[2]);

    return 0;
}
```

There is only one line in my file and this is how it looks like: 6 a11 a22 a33 a44 a55 a66 a77

The first value is an integer which tells me how many strings there are next. i'm storing the values and in a variable using fscanf and trying to assign them into my array, but something weird is happening.

If i printf the values inside the loop right after assigning them, they are displayed correctly. However, if i try to print after exiting the loop, no matter what index i choose, the same value is always displayed, instead of the ones that were showing inside the loop

The output i'm getting is:

> a11
> a22
> a33
> a44
> a55
> a66
> element: a66
> element: a66
> element: a66

Comment: `rot[i] = str;` that points every array entry to the **same** buffer. So all entries change every time `str` changes.

Comment: One solution is to make a copy of the string: `rot[i] = strdup(str)`. Don't forget to `free` all the `rot` entries when they are no longer needed.